# route rails 2 to rails 4 "map.connect"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, migrate

i Have this route in rails 2.3.14 that i want to convert to rails 4.0.3

## map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'

## map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'

I try using match, but give me error.

Comment: what you tried and what's the error ?

Comment: match ':controller/:action/:id'
match ':controller/:action/:id.:format'

Comment: gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:191:in `normalize_conditions!': You should not use the `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method. (RuntimeError)
If you want to expose your action to both GET and POST, add `via: [:get, :post]` option.
If you want to expose your action to GET, use `get` in the router:
  Instead of: match "controller#action"
  Do: get "controller#action"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ok, do this

```
 match ':controller/:action/:id', via: [:get, :post]
```

Comment: This is discouraged if it all possible, please consider re-organising your routes file so you specify the routes individually rather than relying on this pattern. It allows you to do gets on a post action and vice-versa

Comment: yes, i know. I guess this comment belongs to questioner. I answered what he asked.I know that's a bad practice.

Comment: thanks for the answer and the advice, i take in consideration.

Comment: @ParitoshPiplewar I agree that this probably does belong to the OP, however by posting it next to the accepted answer means more people considering this approach would read it

Answer (score 0):

If it all possible, consider refactoring your routes file and not using a catch-all. In most cases you will know all the actions that a user may do on your site and you should restrict to this.

By adding a catch all you allow every action to be accessed via get, which could be dangerous. A good discussion on this is available at http://darwinweb.net/articles/the-problem-with-rails-catch-all-route

If you still want to do this and understand the risks then see @ParitoshPiplewar's answer